# Show only row that follow criteria in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

in Excel, how can one filter and just show on the WORKSHEET rows that follow some criteria, for instance, rows that have the value "1" in the second column?

In case it can be done, can I add this action somehow to a button on the toolbar? I use Excel for Mac 2008

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what AutoFilter is for.  [Page 15 of this manual describes it](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=9&ved=0CEUQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.esm.rochester.edu%2Fesmtmp%2Fecs%2Ftutorials%2Fdocuments%2FMicrosoftExcel2008.pdf&ei=LGUDTJ-KNJuINa7T-Ts&usg=AFQjCNEivZzEE8j__2N-c62aKBehaMQORg&sig2=_6C_DhIPG624Zqx3fPh7-w), but really all you need to do is to click your header row and activate the Data menu → Filter → Auto Filter.